# Setting up Subversion Repository on Shared Hosting Server from scratch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, xampp

I have a shared hosting and now i want to setup a `subversion repository` so that I can maintain my website from two different locations i.e. my desktop and laptop.

I have `XAMPP` installed on my both machines with Eclipse and `subversion plugin` installed. Also I have only access to `cpanel` of the hosting server. Is there anyone who could explain the process in easy words?

Can I make use of my shared hosting to host my repository? as well as my deployment code?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make use of my shared hosting to host my repository?

No, you can't (in most common case), because repository require at least installing and running Subversion (not user-level task) and modify Apache-config (in case of Apache and httpd-served repository) (which is also a task not ofr user on shared hosting)

Dreamhost offer SVN-repos as part of webhosting offer, AFAIK